# Using Date to find the inequality for sales than 500

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I'm curious as to find the daily average sales for the month of December 1998 not greater than 100 as a where clause. So what I imagine is that since the table consists of the date of sales (sth like 1 december 1998, consisting of different date, months and year), amount due....First I'm going to define a particular month.

```
DEFINE a = TO_DATE('1-Dec-1998', 'DD-Month-YYYY')
SELECT SUBSTR(Sales_Date, 4,6), (SUM(Amount_Due)/EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(Sales_Date))
FROM ......
WHERE SUM(AMOUNT_DUE)/EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(&a)) < 100
```

I'm stuck as to extract the sum of amount due in the month of december 1998 for the where clause....
How can I achieve the objective?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your question. Are you storing dates as strings?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like this:

```
select to_char(sales_date, 'mm.yyyy') month,
       avg(amount_due) avg_value
from your_table
where sales_date >= trunc(date '1998-12-01', 'mm')
  and sales_date <  add_months(trunc(date '1998-12-01', 'mm'), 1)
group by to_char(sales_date, 'mm.yyyy')
having avg(amount_due) < 100;
```

`WHERE` clause can be simplified; it shows how to fetch certain period:

- `trunc` to `mm` returns first day in that month
- `add_months` to the above value (*first day in that month*) will return first day of the **next** month
- the bottom line: give me all rows whose `sales_date` is `>=` first day of this month and `<` first day of the next month; basically, the whole *this* month

Finally, the `where` clause you used should actually be the `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the amount_due column only contains numbers, you can use the sum function.

Below SQL query should be able to satisfy your requirement.

```
Select SUM(Amount_Due) from table Sales where Sales_Date between '1-12-1998' and '31-12-1998'
```

OR

```
Select SUM(Amount_Due) from table Sales where Sales_Date like '%-12-1998'
```

Comment: Using `LIKE` on a DATE column is a really bad advice